# How to find the map-side sort time in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am investigating the performance of out algorithm that runs on top of Hadoop 2.x. We would like to know how the calculation time breaks down in different pieces:
- map time
- reduce time
- sort time
- shuffle time

on the reduce side, there is a clear distinction in the counters: each of the components (reduce, shuffle, merge) has a separate counter. On the map side, there is also a sort taking place, but I cannot find the counters that are related to the sort time/amount. How can I find out the map side sort time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about Map side sort/spill. You can look [here](http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/mr-perf) for a good presentation on performance, at eash stage of mapreduce. Also in **Hadoop Definitve guide, Chapter 6 - How Map reduce works, Shuffle and Sort, Map side**, for more theory

Comment: presentation in helpful in gaining insight in the inner workings, thanks. But I would like to know if there is an inner counter I can use for finding out the map side sort time. There is the spill amount, which gives an indication, but the time fraction a mapper spends on sorting would be really helpful for our research.